# groovy script in jenkins fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script which works fine for all jenkins job but fails for one jenkin jobs.
It works fine in Jenkins scriptler but does not work when I create the job dsl in groovy.

```
parameters {
activeChoiceParam('BRANCH') {
 com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class

    """)
    }
}
```

fails with error

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: github_token for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.parameter.ActiveChoiceGroovyScriptContext
```

Comment: Replac `${github_token.password}` with real password

Comment: why ? I dont want to use real password

Comment: the same code works for other jobs

Comment: With plain text for token it works, what I am doing wrong

Comment: Have you tried `\${github_token.password}` (quote the dollar sign)

Comment: "\${github_token.password}" like this ?

Comment: Also both `github_token` and `jenkinsCredentials` is the same. You can use only one, with `jenkinsCredentials.getPassword()` or `github_token.getPassword()` with `\$`

Comment: without quotes ?

Comment: As @cfrick write. `\${github_token.getPassword()}`

Comment: this worked 'Authorization: token \${github_token.password}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using triple quotes, the GString replacement still works.  So writing `${...}` in such a string will replace the variable at once.  But you want to delay this until the script is run.  So you have to quote the dollar sign.  e.g.

```
...
inputFile.write("curl ... -H 'Authorization: token \${github_token.password}'...")
...
```

Or use triple single quotes (if you don't want any replacements for that string at all)

Comment: and I am doing,  import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.* 
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*, are these all required?

Comment: import jenkins.* and import hudson.* only

Comment: also this groovy script .adds a new line in the . beginning. how can I remove that line.

Comment: hey do you know how how to write jenkins declarative pipelines?